# Why I need 4 previousSibling to get 2 previous element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In this example, I want to get the value of 2 previous sibling

But this is not work `btn.previousSibling.previousSibling.value`

I need use 4 previousSibling to get the value, why 4?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function text(btn){
    console.log(btn.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.value)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="text(this)">text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the expected output? I cannot find  4 siblings of button

Comment: @brk He is asking..to get the result of the text box... why we need to have 4x `previousSibling` properties

Comment: That has to do with text nodes, if you remove the indentation, enters and and spaces around the tags `<button>` up to `<textarea>` it will work as you intended

Comment: @HimanshuBansal where is text box do you mean `text area`?

Comment: @CL So 1st sibling is button..2nd is text..3rd is br..then 4th is textarea..from where you get the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`previousSibling` points to the previous `Node`, which is new line (a `TextNode`) in your example. You might want to use `previousElementSibling` instead

```js
function text(btn){
  console.log(
    btn
      .previousElementSibling
      .previousElementSibling
      .value
  );
}
```

```html
<textarea>Hello</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="text(this)">text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of empty entries inserted by the browser :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling

this code works in your case :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function text(btn){
    alert(btn.previousSibling.previousSibling.value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>test text</textarea><br><button onclick="text(this)">text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use JQuery $(btn).prev().prev();

Like :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
function text(btn){
    alert($(btn).prev().prev().val());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>test text</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="text(this)">text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of the `br` element. 
You can get the parent using `parentNode` and `queryselector` to get the specific element.

```js
function text(btn) {
  var getText = btn.parentNode.querySelector('textarea').value;
  console.log(getText.trim())
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="text(this)">text</button>
```